# a partition device does not exist, though present on fdisk -l

Tags: linux, centos

On Centos 7.7 I run commands:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/500MB.img bs=1M count=500
500+0 records in
500+0 records out
524288000 bytes (524 MB) copied, 0.374844 s, 1.4 GB/s
# losetup --all
# losetup /dev/loop0 ./500MB.img
# losetup --all
/dev/loop0: [64768]:33575036 (/root/500MB.img)
# fdisk -l /dev/loop0

Disk /dev/loop0: 524 MB, 524288000 bytes, 1024000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
# fdisk /dev/loop0
[here set partition]
# fdisk -l /dev/loop0

Disk /dev/loop0: 524 MB, 524288000 bytes, 1024000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b7a6a60

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/loop0p1            2048     1023999      510976   83  Linux
#
```

However the /dev/loop0p1 doesn't exist in the system:

```
# pvcreate /dev/loop0p1
  Device /dev/loop0p1 not found.
# ls -ld /dev/loop0p1
ls: cannot access /dev/loop0p1: No such file or directory
# kpartx -l /dev/loop0
loop0p1 : 0 1021952 /dev/loop0 2048
# ls -ld /dev/loop0p1
ls: cannot access /dev/loop0p1: No such file or directory
```

Only the loop-disk device exists:

```
# ls -ld /dev/loop0
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 7, 0 Apr 23 09:31 /dev/loop0
```

Where is the partition showed on "fdisk -l"?

Update:
Fixed thanks to Stephen Kitt's hints.
All steps run to fix:

```
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
# losetup --all
# ls /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0
# fdisk -l /dev/loop0
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
# fdisk -l ./500MB.img

Disk ./500MB.img: 524 MB, 524288000 bytes, 1024000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b7a6a60

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
./500MB.img1            2048     1023999      510976   83  Linux
# losetup -P /dev/loop0 ./500MB.img
# losetup --all
/dev/loop0: [64768]:33575036 (/root/500MB.img)
# ls -ld /dev/loop0*
brw-rw----. 1 root disk   7, 0 Apr 23 10:16 /dev/loop0
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 259, 0 Apr 23 10:16 /dev/loop0p1
#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the kernel to scan the partitions; one way to do that is to use `losetup`, assuming your partition table is written before the device is mounted:

- run `fdisk` on your image
- check the partition table with `fdisk -l` on the image
- add the `-P` option to `losetup`: `losetup -P /dev/loop0 ./500MB.img`

The last step will scan the partitions in the loop device, and you’ll see `/dev/loop0p1`.